# ReadFile() WinApi assembler

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm

I came across a strange problem with ReadFile(). The textfile is opened correctly but it reads only 4 bytes instead of number of bytes declared in MemorySize. The same code in C is executed properly. Somebody knows what's wrong?

Regards

```
.DATA
FileName DB "test.txt",0
MemorySize  DWORD 10

.DATA?
hFile    HANDLE ?
pMemory  DWORD  ?
SizeR    DWORD  ?

.CODE
start:

INVOKE CreateFile, ADDR FileName,\ 
    GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL,\
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL
mov hFile, eax
INVOKE GlobalAlloc, GMEM_FIXED or GMEM_ZEROINIT, MemorySize+1
mov pMemory, eax
INVOKE ReadFile, hFile, ADDR pMemory, MemorySize, ADDR SizeR, NULL
INVOKE MessageBox, 0, ADDR pMemory, 0, 0
INVOKE LocalFree, pMemory
INVOKE CloseHandle, hFile
ret
end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INVOKE ReadFile, hFile, ADDR pMemory, MemorySize, ADDR SizeR, NULL
INVOKE MessageBox, 0, ADDR pMemory, 0, 0
```

In these two lines, you are passing a pointer to a pointer for pMemory.  GlobalAlloc returns a pointer to memory and ReadFile expects a pointer NOT a pointer to a pointer.  Remove ADDR and it should work.

```
INVOKE GlobalAlloc, GMEM_FIXED or GMEM_ZEROINIT, MemorySize+1
```

This is wrong also.  You cannot do MemorySize + 1 as you would to in a High Level Language.  In this case you need to do:

```
inc     MemorySize
```

before your call to GlobalAlloc

Comment: Oh finally.. I ve notices that first mistake but the second one was a bit tricky. Thanks a lot man.